# How to grep keywords with unique value?

Tags: grep, uniq

I just want data those have unique value, say we write log file for mobile users

```
<mobile_number1>|20141006 06:15:26||AKQY6LYACZAA4O|12|3|BIHAR|
<mobile_number2>|20141006 06:16:05||AKQY6MAYAEQALE|12|22|UP EAST|
<mobile_number3>|20141006 06:16:39||AKQY6MQICY4BEQ|12|2|ASSAM|
<mobile_number4>|20141006 06:16:49||AKQY6LUIAE4ACI|12|1|ANDHRA PRADESH| 
<mobile_number1>|20141006 06:17:53||AKQY6NFAAEYAJS|12|23|UP WEST| 
<mobile_number6>|20141006 06:18:09||AKQY6M7ACY4ANG|12|18|ORISSA|
<mobile_number7>|20141006 06:18:54||AKQY6MWQCZAAME|12|20|RAJASTHAN|
<mobile_number1>|20141006 06:19:50||AKQY6N2ACZMA2K|12|1|ANDHRA PRADESH|
```

Now we need to fetch unique mobile number like this.

```
<mobile_number1>
<mobile_number2>
<mobile_number3>
<mobile_number4>
<mobile_number6>
<mobile_number7>
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear at all. What's the use case? Which data do you have before the search, which do you expect as a result? How are entries with the same mobile number grouped?

Comment: I am expecting unique mobile number output instead of repeating number.

Comment: I still don't understand. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/532779/edit) your question with an example of what you expect as output.

Comment: Eventually we found solution to your question, then could you be so kind as to add desired output to your question?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
  sort -t '|' -k 1,1 -u yourFile | awk -F "|" '{print $1}'
```

where:

- `-t '|'` use `|` as separator
- `-k 1,1` use first column as key
- `-u` get unique line using key

`awk` print first column and the result is:

```
<mobile_number1>
<mobile_number2>
<mobile_number3>
<mobile_number4>
<mobile_number6>
<mobile_number7>
```

This script works if each line in `yourFile` has `mobile_number` as first column separated from the rest by `|`.

Comment: I would do `cut -d '|' -f 1 | LC_COLLATE=C sort -u`. It's a bit simpler and puts the projection before the sorting/grouping so to speak.

Comment: Cool! your suggestion is better then mine! I tested on Red Hat Enterprise Linux ES release 4 (Nahant Update 3) and it works like this: cut -d '|' -f 1 | sort -u. Why don't you write your own answer? It is really good!

Comment: Because I don't know yet, what the question aims at – though this is my most prominent suspicion.

Comment: Its works, also found $ cat <filename> | cut -f 1 -d'|'                                           Thanks Letizia.

Comment: @DavidFoerster OP said that he like your suggestion, may be is time to write your answer, if you want :)

Comment: @Jayesh: `cat` is unnecessary in this context. Just do `cut -d '|' -f 1 input-file` or `cut -d '|' -f 1 < input-file`.

Answer (score 2):

To throw away all columns but the first:

```sh
cut -d '|' -f 1
```

To omit recurring lines:

```sh
sort -u
```

Together (with input from a file):

```sh
cut -d '|' -f 1 <FILE> | sort -u
```

This uses the most simple shell utilities to perform the task. No command interpreters like `awk` necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
 awk '!x[$1]++ {print $1}' FS="|" /path/to/file
```

example:

```
[aneesh@mylap /]$  awk '!x[$1]++ {print $1}' FS="|" /tmp/test.txt 

<mobile_number1>
<mobile_number2>
<mobile_number3>
<mobile_number4>
<mobile_number6>
<mobile_number7>
```